# Undefined JavaScript error on value assignment in a function variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS function (called on a button click event) and I am not able to assign a value in the function and show in the alert. I am new to JS and cant figure out what the issue is?

```
function setRecaptchaValueWithinForm(formFieldId)  {
    alert(formFieldId);
    alert("After button click :" + document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value);
    //alert(g-recaptcha-response.value);
    formFieldTuringId.value = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value; 
        alert(formFieldTuringId.value); // throws undefined error.
    }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what this function is being called from? We don't even see what is passed to it.

Comment: You should use `console.log` to debug your page, not `alert`. Where are you defining `formFieldTuringId`?

Comment: Where is `formFieldTuringId` defined? I'm assuming it's defined elsewhere. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also why pass in `formFieldId` if it is not used?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="turing_{ID}" name ="turing_{ID}"  />     <input type="submit" value="ID_SubmitButtonText}" name="submitButton" onClick="setRecaptchaValueWithinForm('turing_{turing_ID}')" />


This function is called on "Submit" button click on a form.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="turing_{ID}" name ="turing_{ID}"  />     <input type="submit" value="ID_SubmitButtonText}" name="submitButton" onClick="setRecaptchaValueWithinForm('turing_{turing_ID}')" />


This function is called on "Submit" button click on a form.